# Gradle Zip task to do multiple sub-trees?

Tags: java, zip, gradle

We're trying to build up a minorly complicated Zip file in Gradle from multiple filesystem source trees, but no matter how many `into` specifications we give, it all puts them in the same one.  Is this possible to do in Gradle?

```
build/libs/foo.jar --> foo.jar
bar/*              --> bar/*
```

We're getting this instead:

```
build/libs/foo.jar --> bar/foo.jar
bar/*              --> bar/*
```

Using this:

```
task installZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: jar) {
    from('build/libs/foo.jar').into('.')
    from('bar').into('bar')
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Gradle 1.0-milestone-3

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
    from jar.outputs.files
    from('bar/') {
        into('bar')
    }
}
```

First... the jar should be in the root / of the zip (which seems to be what you want). Second, by specifying the from `jar.outputs.files`, there is an implicit `dependsOn` on the jar task, so this shows another way of accomplishing what you want. Except with this approach if the jar name changes over time it doesn't matter. Let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that method for pulling in the Jar file or the implicit depencency, so thanks for that.  However, the above still drops the jar files into the bar directory within the Zip file.

Comment: @Alan I thought perhaps this was an issue with the version of gradle.  I just switch to milestone-3 (which is in your notes) and tested this out.   I have a project with the same exact needs and it works fine.  So you will need to share more about your project or build file to diagnose more.

Comment: We ended up trying something else today and mutating it over time, we came to a solution that worked that was much like what you posted.  I'm uncertain why it wasn't working for us yesterday.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently the comments to an answer will not allow for a convenient way to show more code... or it isn't obvious :)  I have a project which is for a client... so I can't share the full project / build file.  Here is what I can share (I changed the project specific acron to XXX):

```
task zip(type: Zip) {

    from jar.outputs.files

    from('scripts/') {
        fileMode = 0755
        include '**/runXXX.sh'
        include '**/runXXX.bat'
    }
    from('lib/') {
        include '**/*.jar'
        into('lib')
    }
    from('.') {
        include 'xxx.config'
    }

}
```

This creates a zip with the project jar in the root of the zip.  Copies the scripts from a directory to the root, copies the config file to the root and creates a directory in the root of the zip named /lib and copies all the jars from the project /lib to the zip/lib.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not directly answer the question but I guess this would help someone who writes 'Gradle Plugins'

```
    final Zip zipTask = project.getTasks().create(taskName, Zip.class);
    
    final Action<? super CopySpec> cp1 = (p) -> {
        p.include("**/Install_*.xml", "**/Install.xml").into(WORKING_DIR_1);
    };
    final Action<? super CopySpec> cp2 = (p) -> {
        p.include("*Terminology*.xml").into(WORKING_DIR_2);
    };
    zipTask.from(projectDir + "/Release", cp1);
    zipTask.from(projectDir + "/Release", cp2);
```