# multiple into sections in gradle zip seems to fail

Tags: gradle

Very similar to this question: [Gradle Zip task to do multiple sub-trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022280/gradle-zip-task-to-do-multiple-sub-trees) Which I don't believe is fully answered, merely circumvented..

I have a project with child projects, built with gradle 1.6,  and I need to assemble some results into multiple paths, but I too see the last path surviving.

```
task zip (type: Zip) {
  from ('src/resources') {
    into '/'
  }
  from ('web') {
    into '/'
  }


  from project('A').reference { into ('A') }
  from project('B').reference { into ('B') }
}
```

(Essentially the reference task creates a few directories which are named the same in A and B, so needs to prepend the project name)..

Obviously the references all end up into /B/** in the zip file. When I reverse the order of the two lines, they end up in /A/**. 
The other two goes correctly into /. If I move the subproject up before the root resources, they would still go in either /A or /B depending on their order, but the normal resources end in / as assumed.

I would essentially like to include the subprojects dynamically, i.e.

```
project.subprojects.each {
  def pname = it.name
  from project(pname).reference {
    into "$pname"
  }
}
```

but all my attempts so far has been in vain.

Any pointers welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax doesn't look right. It should be `from(project('A').reference) { into ('A') }`. (Same for `B`.) Does this make a difference?

PS: `into "/"` is redundant and can be omitted.

Comment: Of course, you're right. I omitted the parentheses by accident of course, and it always tend to bite you :)